# Can I create aliases of views too? I'm working in SAP BusinessObjects IDT Data Foundation Layer and working with a Calendar view

Tags: sql, business-objects

I'm working in SAP BusinessObjects IDT Data Foundation Layer and working with a Calendar view which I want to join with the fact table which has multiple date fields.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely.  From the perspective of a BO universe, there is no difference between a physical table and a view.  What you've described is very commonly done.